# Websocket classloading in Embedded Jetty

Tags: java, maven, embedded-jetty, java-websocket

I am having some trouble with websockets in an embedded jetty webserver. Use the following setup:

- Embedded Jetty version 9.3
- Five different wars, each loaded in webappcontext, with configurations added for Annotations and the like. ParentLoaderPriority set to true
- One of the wars contains a websocket, implemented using websocketlistener interface (native jetty websocket). Connected through a WebSocketServlet that registers the websocket.
- Same war contains a simple html page with a javascript that connects to the websocket by calling the servlet.

Dependency-wise, the pom of the war contains the jetty.websocket.**servlet** dependency, the pom of the embedded server contains the jetty.websocket.**server** dependency. Nothing else websocket wise.

When I run this, the websocket call in the html gives an error. Logging shows a NoClassDefFoundException for jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory. Apparently, something goes awry with classloading, but I cannot determine how to fix it.

Here's what I've tried (to no avail) thus far:

- Adding the websocket as a Servlet to embedded jetty (so not in webappcontext, but servletContextHandler) -> works fine
- Set classloaderpriority to false.
- Checked System and Server classes and manually setting them as per jetty documentation. "org.eclipse.jetty.websocket." is registered as System class.
- Adding jetty.websocket.server (and jetty.websocket.api) as dependency to the WAR (in addition to server). This gives a different error, since conflicts between parent and war classloader. Setting scope to provided for server dependency reverts the error to aforementioned ClassDefNotFound exception.
- Adding the jetty.websocket.server location to the class-path of the war.

I am out of ideas. Any suggestions on what else to try are greatly appreciated!

**Edit: Found it**

The problem was not in the jetty config, but in a service wrapper used for starting the embedded server. I incorrectly configured this wrapper, so that the websocket dependencies were not on the class path when running the server. Fixing the wrapper caused the websockets to work correctly. No changes to the jetty config required.

Comment: Are you leaving the original JARs alone? or doing any kind of uber jar / shading / merging of the classes?

Comment: No, all server dependencies, including the embedded server jar are assembled in lib directory. All war files are assembled in wars directory and extracted to temp directory.

Comment: Are you using any sort of alternate classloading, such as OSGi, JPMS/Jigsaw?

Comment: Ugh, sorry, I may have wasted your time. As you probably suspected, it had nothing to do with the Jetty config. The problem was in the service wrapper for the application, in which I made an error in the config of the classpath. So the websocket dependencies were not present on the classpath of the server jar when running as service. Thanks for your time